# Why use external storage for Intent data?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send images created using my app using a send intent.
I looked at many examples of such intents and noticed that they all used the external storage to store the temporary image files that will be sent using the intent.

Is there any specific reason why the external storage is being used?
It looks to me like a dangerous choice since the user wouldn't be able to post images to the web if the external storage is not mounted, which feels rather strange.

Also, where would you save your app's working data? In onPause(), I am saving the current image the user is working on in the internal storage, but would you recommend storing it in external storage instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common because images can be fairly large. In some devices internal storage is somewhat precious (hence the popularity of Apps2SD). Additionally, sometimes you might want these images accessible to the user outside of your app. If it's truly just temporary, you should consider using [`getCacheDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) or [`getExternalCacheDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29).

See [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for info on storage. There's [code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#MediaAvail) in that doc to see if external storage is available if you want to use internal and fallback to external.

Oh, the main reason though in your scenario is simply that your chunk of internal storage is only accessible to your app. If the send intent is to a component that is not your app, it won't be able to access your area of internal storage.

Comment: Yes, the image is only stored there to be able to send a Uri to it in a send intent in order to allow the user to post it on Twitter/ Facebook / whatever. I would delete it afterwards. Couldn't I make it available to other apps if I use [openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with [MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)?

Comment: Yeah, that's true, you could create it with `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` or `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` and it should work. I don't see anything inherently *wrong* with using internal storage in your scenario, just trying to explain why all the examples use external.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that there is a limit to IPC data in Android -- around 1MB. That means that if you put more than that in your intent's extras, you will get an error when you try to start an activity using this intent. So the only way to pass images via intents is to pass a pointer (URL, filename) to the actual image. Since private files are only visible to your application you have to either store to external (shared) storage or pass a content provider URI (you need to write the content provider, of course). Shared storage is the easier way.

Answer (score 0):

An Image is in a byte array format. when you are sending directly, it might be possible that it takes time ( i.e. if you are sending on remote server ). Sometimes application may get hung. So to avoid such sequential programming, developer uses parallel code, here one code save the image in storage device and another works for uploading part.

One More Benefit is that direct sending can causes in data loss while saving on external storage prevents such cases.